# Arm template will not deploy. Says missing NSG resource, but it's included in the template

Tags: azure, templates, visual-studio-code, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

The problem:  This is being deployed with azure pipelines, and has passed local validation and vscode ide validation.  I have tried every solution I've found on MSFT docs, and several in SOF.  I cannot make this thing deploy.

The error I'm getting:

```
    ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/UnityServer-NSG-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX' is not defined in the template.
    ##[warning]Validation errors were found in the Azure Resource Manager template. 
    Starting Deployment.
    Deployment name is XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-unityserver-deploy
    There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
    ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment 
        "code": "InvalidTemplate",
        "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/UnityServer-NSG-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX' is not defined in the template. 
    ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

The template in question:

```
    {
        "$schema": "X",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
          "Subscription-Id": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Environment": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Location": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "IsThisProduction": {
            "defaultValue": "false",
            "allowedValues": [
              "false",
              "true"
            ],
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Unity-Server-Resource-Group-Name": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "UnityServer-RG-Env-Location"
          },
          "UberMgmt-Resource-Group-Name-For-Region": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "andrew_blue-green_mgmt"
          },
          "UberMgmt-VNET-Name-For-Region": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXX"
          },
          "UberMgmt-VNET-Subnet-Name-For-Region": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
          },
          "Unity-Server-VM-Name": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Unity-Server-NIC-Name": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Unity-Server-PublicIp-Reservation-Name": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Unity-Server-NSG-Name": {
            "defaultValue": "UnityServer-NSG-Env-Location",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name": {
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "type": "String"
          },
          "XXXXXXXXXXXXBaseImageGallery-External-Id": {
            "defaultValue": "galleryID string here",
            "type": "String"
          }
        },
        "variables": {
          "Prod-Or-Non-Prod": "[if(equals(parameters('IsThisProduction'), 'true'), 'Prod', 'Non-Prod')]",
          "Deployment-Name": "[concat('XXXXXXXXXXXX-Deploy-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'))]"
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-Resource-Group-Name')]",
            "properties": {},
            "tags": {
              "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-RG-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
              "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
              "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
              "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
              "VantaOwner": "Devops"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "name": "[string(variables('Deployment-Name'))]",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('Unity-Server-Resource-Group-Name')]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', parameters('Unity-Server-Resource-Group-Name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {},
                "variables": {},
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-NSG-Name')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-NSG-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "properties": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-PublicIp-Reservation-Name')]",
                    "location": "eastus",
                    "tags": {tagshere},
                    "sku": {
                      "name": "Standard",
                      "tier": "Regional"
                    },
                    "zones": [
                      "1"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "ipAddress": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
                      "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                      "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                      "ipTags": []
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name')]",
                    "location": "eastus",
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-Backup-Services-Vault-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "sku": {
                      "name": "RS0",
                      "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "properties": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name')]",
                    "location": "eastus",
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-Diag-Storage-Account-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "sku": {
                      "name": "Standard_GRS",
                      "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "kind": "StorageV2",
                    "properties": {
                      "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
                      "networkAcls": {
                        "bypass": "AzureServices",
                        "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                        "ipRules": [],
                        "defaultAction": "Allow"
                      },
                      "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                      "encryption": {
                        "services": {
                          "file": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                          },
                          "blob": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                          }
                        },
                        "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                      },
                      "accessTier": "Hot"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-VM-Name')]",
                    "location": "eastus",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-Virtual-Machine-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": true,
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "zones": [
                      "1"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "hardwareProfile": {
                        "vmSize": "Standard_B2s"
                      },
                      "storageProfile": {
                        "imageReference": {
                          "id": "[concat(parameters('XXXXXXXXXXXXBaseImageGallery-External-Id'), '/images/XXXXXXXXXXXXBaseImage-Centos8.3-gen2')]"
                        },
                        "osDisk": {
                          "osType": "Linux",
                          "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-VM-Name'), '_OsDisk')]",
                          "createOption": "FromImage",
                          "caching": "ReadWrite",
                          "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
                          },
                          "diskSizeGB": 30
                        },
                        "dataDisks": []
                      },
                      "networkProfile": {
                        "networkInterfaces": [
                          {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('Unity-Server-NIC-Name'))]"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "diagnosticsProfile": {
                        "bootDiagnostics": {
                          "enabled": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-NSG-Name'), '/SSH')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('Unity-Server-NSG-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "protocol": "TCP",
                      "sourcePortRange": "*",
                      "destinationPortRange": "22",
                      "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                      "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                      "access": "Allow",
                      "priority": 300,
                      "direction": "Inbound",
                      "sourcePortRanges": [],
                      "destinationPortRanges": [],
                      "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                      "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'), '/DefaultPolicy')]",
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-Backup-Policy-Default-Policy-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
                      "instantRPDetails": {},
                      "schedulePolicy": {
                        "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy",
                        "scheduleRunFrequency": "Daily",
                        "scheduleRunTimes": [
                          "2021-06-15T01:00:00Z"
                        ],
                        "scheduleWeeklyFrequency": 0
                      },
                      "retentionPolicy": {
                        "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
                        "dailySchedule": {
                          "retentionTimes": [
                            "2021-06-15T01:00:00Z"
                          ],
                          "retentionDuration": {
                            "count": 30,
                            "durationType": "Days"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "instantRpRetentionRangeInDays": 2,
                      "timeZone": "UTC",
                      "protectedItemsCount": 0
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'), '/HourlyLogBackup')]",
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-Backup-Policy-Hourly-Log-Backup-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "backupManagementType": "AzureWorkload",
                      "workLoadType": "SQLDataBase",
                      "settings": {
                        "timeZone": "UTC",
                        "issqlcompression": false,
                        "isCompression": false
                      },
                      "subProtectionPolicy": [
                        {
                          "policyType": "Full",
                          "schedulePolicy": {
                            "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy",
                            "scheduleRunFrequency": "Daily",
                            "scheduleRunTimes": [
                              "2021-06-15T01:00:00Z"
                            ],
                            "scheduleWeeklyFrequency": 0
                          },
                          "retentionPolicy": {
                            "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
                            "dailySchedule": {
                              "retentionTimes": [
                                "2021-06-15T01:00:00Z"
                              ],
                              "retentionDuration": {
                                "count": 30,
                                "durationType": "Days"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "policyType": "Log",
                          "schedulePolicy": {
                            "schedulePolicyType": "LogSchedulePolicy",
                            "scheduleFrequencyInMins": 60
                          },
                          "retentionPolicy": {
                            "retentionPolicyType": "SimpleRetentionPolicy",
                            "retentionDuration": {
                              "count": 30,
                              "durationType": "Days"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "protectedItemsCount": 0
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'), '/UnityServerEastusBackupPolicy')]",
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-Backup-Policy-Unity-Server-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
                      "instantRPDetails": {
                        "azureBackupRGNamePrefix": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Resource-Group-Name'), 'backup')]",
                        "azureBackupRGNameSuffix": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Resource-Group-Name'), 'unityserver')]"
                      },
                      "schedulePolicy": {
                        "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy",
                        "scheduleRunFrequency": "Daily",
                        "scheduleRunTimes": [
                          "2021-06-14T08:00:00Z"
                        ],
                        "scheduleWeeklyFrequency": 0
                      },
                      "retentionPolicy": {
                        "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
                        "dailySchedule": {
                          "retentionTimes": [
                            "2021-06-14T08:00:00Z"
                          ],
                          "retentionDuration": {
                            "count": 30,
                            "durationType": "Days"
                          }
                        },
                        "weeklySchedule": {
                          "daysOfTheWeek": [
                            "Sunday"
                          ],
                          "retentionTimes": [
                            "2021-06-14T08:00:00Z"
                          ],
                          "retentionDuration": {
                            "count": 4,
                            "durationType": "Weeks"
                          }
                        },
                        "monthlySchedule": {
                          "retentionScheduleFormatType": "Weekly",
                          "retentionScheduleWeekly": {
                            "daysOfTheWeek": [
                              "Sunday"
                            ],
                            "weeksOfTheMonth": [
                              "First"
                            ]
                          },
                          "retentionTimes": [
                            "2021-06-14T08:00:00Z"
                          ],
                          "retentionDuration": {
                            "count": 12,
                            "durationType": "Months"
                          }
                        },
                        "yearlySchedule": {
                          "retentionScheduleFormatType": "Weekly",
                          "monthsOfYear": [
                            "January"
                          ],
                          "retentionScheduleWeekly": {
                            "daysOfTheWeek": [
                              "Sunday"
                            ],
                            "weeksOfTheMonth": [
                              "First"
                            ]
                          },
                          "retentionTimes": [
                            "2021-06-14T08:00:00Z"
                          ],
                          "retentionDuration": {
                            "count": 3,
                            "durationType": "Years"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "instantRpRetentionRangeInDays": 3,
                      "timeZone": "UTC",
                      "protectedItemsCount": 0
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/replicationAlertSettings",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'), '/defaultAlertSetting')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "sendToOwners": "DoNotSend",
                      "customEmailAddresses": []
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/replicationVaultSettings",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'), '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('Unity-Server-Backup-Services-Vault-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'), '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "sku": {
                      "name": "Standard_GRS",
                      "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                      "cors": {
                        "corsRules": []
                      },
                      "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                        "enabled": false
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'), '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "sku": {
                      "name": "Standard_GRS",
                      "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                      "protocolSettings": {
                        "smb": {}
                      },
                      "cors": {
                        "corsRules": []
                      },
                      "shareDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "days": 7
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'), '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "cors": {
                        "corsRules": []
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'), '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('Unity-Server-Storage-Account-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                      "cors": {
                        "corsRules": []
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('Unity-Server-NIC-Name')]",
                    "location": "eastus",
                    "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('Unity-Server-PublicIp-Reservation-Name'))]",
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('Unity-Server-NSG-Name'))]"
                    ],
                    "tags": {
                      "VantaDescription": "[concat('UnityServer-', parameters('Environment'), '-', parameters('Location'), '-NIC-', string(variables('Prod-Or-Non-Prod')))]",
                      "VantaNonProd": "parameters('IsThisProduction')",
                      "VantaContainsUserData": "false",
                      "VantaUserDataStored": "n/a",
                      "VantaOwner": "Devops"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                      "ipConfigurations": [
                        {
                          "name": "ipconfig1",
                          "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('Unity-Server-PublicIp-Reservation-Name'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('UberMgmt-VNET-Name-For-Region'), parameters('UberMgmt-VNET-Subnet-Name-For-Region'))]"
                            },
                            "primary": true,
                            "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "dnsSettings": {
                        "dnsServers": []
                      },
                      "enableAcceleratedNetworking": false,
                      "enableIPForwarding": false,
                      "networkSecurityGroup": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('Unity-Server-NSG-Name'))]"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "outputs": {}
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried deploying the inner template on its own by copying the outer params and variables to the inner scope and running a test deploy? Might get a more specific complaint from ARM.

Comment: It was originally deploying to an already created resource group, and was still giving issues.  The docket for today is to take piece by piece (as I can) and try to deploy the chunks aiming for a more specific complaint. Then once I have deployable chunks (hopefully) see if I can make them go together.

Comment: Going down this path now.  I've split the deploy into 2 runs.  One for the RG, and one for everything else.  Same params file for both.  Both still validate.  Hopefully I either get a deploy success, or a better error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had timing issues around ARM templates that contain networking components before. Where I create a website that has VNET components in the ARM Template, and the issue was it would start the VNET deployment, and then the website would try to deploy, but the VNET wasn't created yet, it was in progress. I ended up writing two ARM Templates, one creates the RSG, and networking components, then the second would create the Website once the networking side was done deploying.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to not have happen, but I believe is actually breaking something.  I don't think it's networking coming online per se, but maybe.  There is already a dependency in the template that is supposed to stop this, but I'm not better than creating an RG in one template and then creating everything else :)  Still a better idea than just throwing my computer out the window, which is where I was.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This wound up being one of the actual issues.  I had to break the template into parts and deploy the parts separately because ARM was not properly respecting the dependencies.  Also there were some SUPER embedded name issues where there are resources expecting to be named "default" explicitly ... These errors of course only showed after breaking out the templates to the point where I was pretty much deploying individual sets of resources.  The ARM error output is little more than useless especially when it comes to nested deployments (their solution btw for deploying rg and resources together)

Comment: Another option, is run the ARM template again. In my case, of the Web App, and its depends-on VNET, even though both were in the same ARM Template, just kicking off the VNET met the depends-on condition, so the Web App when then try to deploy, which would fail due to the VNET not being fully deployed where the Web App could use it. after the error wait a few minutes for the depends-on resources to be created, then run the ARM template again. It won't try to create a RS that already exists, so then the Web App could deploy. Perhaps write a PowerShell script that try the template a few times

Comment: how would you get the second to use the output of the first in case where resource names and id are dynamically generated?